# Contagem regressiva js

Tags: javascript

Tenho um código que conta regressivamente de 20 a 0. Nesse determinado tempo, o usuário tem de fazer determinadas tarefas e quando completar, ele aperta um botão. Na hora que ele aperta o botão, o contador tem de parar no exato segundo em que foi apertado.
Segue os códigos:

JavaScript:

```
var count = new Number();
var count = 21;  
    function start(){
        if((count - 1) >= 0){
            count = count - 1;
            tempo.innerText=count;
            setTimeout('start();',1000);
            console.log("tempo:" + count);
        }
}
```

Tentei criar o seguinte if para parar assim que o botão for `disabled` (que no caso é no exato momento em que é clicado e isso é importante):

```
if(document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled == true){
clearTimeout(count);
}
```

Porém esse if não funciona e não consigo pensar em mais nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma variável para conter o seu *timer*, para que ao clicar num botão possa parar usando `clearInterval`.

Veja esse exemplo:

```js
var count = new Number();
var count = 21;  
// variável para o contador
var contador;
var tempo = document.getElementById("tempo");

function start(){
  if((count - 1) >= 0){
    count = count - 1;
    
    tempo.innerText=count;
    contador = setTimeout(start,1000);
    console.log("tempo:" + count);
  }
}

function stop() {
  tempo.innerText = "Parado em " + count;
  clearInterval(contador);
}

// adiciona um evento para parar ao clicar no botão
document.getElementById("parar").addEventListener("click", stop, false); 

start();
```

```html
<p>
   <span id="tempo"></span>
</p>
<p>
  <button id="parar">
    Parar contador
  </button>
</p>
```